# JSON.stringify() fails to work

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, stringify

When trying to use a `JSON.stringify()` method to turn an array of strings into a JSON object that I can pass through to a PHP script, the `stringify()` method fails to return anything of significance.

This is the only code that the input is being passed through. It is not being tampered with by anything else.

```
function submitItem() {
 try {
    var item = [];
    item.name = $('.itemText').val();
    item.type = $('.itemType').val();
    item.price = $('.itemPrice').val();
    item.color = $('.itemColor').val();
    item.desc = $('.itemDesc').val();
    item.image = $('.itemImage').val();
    item.giftType = $('.itemGiftType').val();
    item.avail = $('.itemAvail').val();
    item.giftable = $('.itemGiftable').val();
    item.ranking = $('.itemRanking').val();
    item.basicTrack = $('.itemBasic').val();
    item.vetTrack = $('.itemVet').val();
    item.month = $('.itemMonth').is(':checked');
    item.hidden = $('.itemHidden').is(':checked');
    item.id = $('.itemID').val();

     //Left in for confirmation purposes
    var join = [];
    join[0] = 'test';
    join[1] = 'tset';
    console.log( JSON.stringify( join ) );

    console.log(item);
    var JsonItem = JSON.stringify(item);
    console.log( JsonItem );
 } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
 }
}
```

This produces the following output in the console:

[image: The output corresponds to the three console.log() lines at the bottom of the script]

As you can see, the log for both JSON items returns as `[]` rather than any JSON string of any sort.

Any potential reason that this would occur would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Arrays stringify based on their numerally-named properties (`1`, `2`, etc.), not their non-numeral properties (`id`, `name`, etc.).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're initializing your "item" as an array. You should be initializing it as a plain object (`{}`):

```
var item = {};
```

When the JSON serializer sees an actual array, it only operates on the numerically-indexed properties.

Comment: Will accept the answer when the timer is done. Didn't realise that before. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You should convert join to object before stringify

```
console.log( JSON.stringify( {arr: join}) );
```

Comment: Smart answer. Wonder why nobody sees it this way...